# Is left to right a higher precedence then the object String?

Tags: java

Is left to right a higher precedence then the object String?

For my print statement as below I got this. Please explain.

```
class triangle{
public static void main(String[]args){
    System.out.println(1+2+"hello");
    System.out.println("hello"+1+2);

    }
}
```

Also why do I need to put a cast to a floating x=1.2F;
and not double x=1.2;?

Comment: what is you expected output, what is your actual output?  Question answered I think.

Comment: Please do not ask two questions in one.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `String + something` what are you doing it is concatenating both elements, not sum the numbers.

You can concatenate two Strings like this:

```
string1 + string2
```

but also you can do

```
"" + string1
```

It only takes part if you are using a plus element after an String. If you sum before the String, the result of your sum will be shown and then the String will be concatenate to that sum.

You can also check on [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for more info (in the first section).

Comment: Well in the second case it does     System.out.println(1+2+"hello");

Comment: for this the outcome is 3hello

Comment: @eli Now it is. I saw it in a bad way.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator is left associative. Whether concatenation happens or summation happens is a result of the left-associativity.